# How to allow web applications from different Azure accounts (company) to allow mutual access over the Internet?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want my web app to be able to send requests to another web app,
I have added the (Outbound) Public IP of the web apps to the mutual access restriction.
In Kudu Console, I use "tcpping" to test that the hostname of his web app is connected (443port).
But I execute my web app with postman and my web app is getting "Forbidden".
Later, when I executed curl  in the Kudu Console of my web app, I also received 403 Forbidden.
And the Kudu Console of the other party's web app executes curl  and displays 401,
In addition to Access Restriction, do I need to confirm any settings?

Comment: 403 Forbidden - Check if the e web app has been stopped in the portal.

Comment: Please refer [Troubleshooting common authentication errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors#unauthorized-error)

Answer (score 0):

As HarshithaVeeramalla-MT said, it was later found that the outbound IP addresses of both parties were not complete, and all IP addresses of Additional Outbound IP Addresses need to be added to the Netowrking/Access Restriction before they can access each other.
Thank you.